# Checking correctness of basic number theory proof

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

The question: Let $a$ and $b$ be positive integers. Suppose that there are integers $u$ and $v$ satisfying $au + bv = 1$. Prove that $\text{gcd}(a, b)=1$.

My attempt: By the equations $u=u_0 + \frac{bk}{\text{gcd}(a, b)}$ and $v = v_0 - \frac{ak}{\text{gcd}(a,b)}$,
  given that $au + bv = 1$ and we want to prove that $\text{gcd}(a, b) = 1$, we can set $au + bv = \text{gcd}(a, b)$ and reduce the left hand side to the right hand side. Since $u_0$ and $v_0$ are solutions to $au + bv$, and $u$ and $v$ satisfy the equation already, $u_0 = u$ and $v_0 = v$. Thus
$$au + bv = \text{gcd}(a,b)$$
$$a\left( u_0 + \frac{bk}{\text{gcd}(a, b)} \right) + b \left(v_0 - \frac{ak}{\text{gcd}(a,b)} \right) = \text{gcd}(a,b)$$
$$au_0 + \frac{abk}{\text{gcd}(a, b)} + bv_0 - \frac{abk}{\text{gcd}(a, b)}=\text{gcd}(a,b)$$
$$au_0 + \require{cancel} \cancel{\frac{abk}{\text{gcd}(a, b)}} + bv_0 - \cancel{\frac{abk}{\text{gcd}(a, b)}}=\text{gcd}(a,b)$$
$$au_0 + bv_0 = \text{gcd}(a,b)$$
$$au+bv=\text{gcd}(a,b)$$
$$1=\text{gcd}(a,b)$$
$$\text{gcd}(a,b)=1$$

Comment: Where did $u_0$ and $v_0$ come from? did you mean to set $au_0 + bv_0 = \gcd (a, b)$

Comment: edited slightly for clarity

Comment: Your arguments are still not clear to me... How can you say that $au + bv = \gcd (a, b)$? Besides, you start with $au + bv = \gcd (a, b)$, then makes some change of variables and then deduce back $au + bv = \gcd (a, b)$... I can't really see the logic behind what you wrote... Maybe you would like to put more details? Use the words "Denote" and "It follows" and "Let there be" and "for some..." so we will know where the different variables came from

Comment: It's much simpler: $\ d\mid a,b\,\Rightarrow\, d\mid au,bv\,\Rightarrow\,d\mid au+bv = 1 $ and this proof shows it is true in any ring (even rings that don't enjoy Bezout linear gcds).

Answer (score 1):

If $\gcd(a,b)=d$ then $1$ divided by $d$ and we are done!